# <c:when> inside <c:choose>

Tags: jsp, loops, jstl

I was wondering whether the below code is valid? I am working on a project and I come from non java background. Do I need to enclose the `<c:otherwise>` with `<c:choose>`? all your help is highly appreciated.

```
 <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${empty example1}">
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
         <c:when test="${empty example2}">
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
         </c:otherwise>
     </c:otherwise>     
  </c:choose>
```

Comment: Well this sure as hell isn't java. Please tag it for what it is.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am trying to add a condition not sure whether I am in the right direction. I looks similar to if else loop. not sure whether I can do the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is.  But even if it is, you can specify multiple "when" clauses.  You'd get the same effect that I think you're after with the much more readable:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${empty example2}">
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Actually I need to check a condition in <c:otherwise> and only display it when the condition satisfies. Based on the condition I want a text to be displayed at the end.

Comment: But this works that way.  If you fail the first "When" it drops into the second "when" and tests that condition.  It's the same thing as if  you dropped into the "otherwise" clause and then set up a new test, only easier to read.

If you really want to, you can put another choose-when-otherwise within the otherwise clause.  But you don't need it here.

Comment: <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${empty example2}">
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise> <c:choose> <c:when test="${empty example3"></c:when></<c:choose>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
Do this should be valid right?

Comment: Looks valid to me.  You'll find out for sure when you put that into your page.  =)

Comment: `c:when` is different from `c:if`, because it's inside a `c:choose` block, as @Marvo pointed out.  `c:choose` means that the conditions are mutually exclusive--only one of the `c:when` conditions will be matched before it stops processing the `c:choose`.

Answer (score 3):

@Marvo nailed it.  The [JSTL 1.2 spec](http://java.coe.psu.ac.th/J2EE/JSTL1.2/jstl-1_2-mrel2-spec.pdf) states that `c:choose` must be the parent of at least one `c:when` statement, and that `c:when` must always precede at least one `c:otherwise` statement with the same immediate parent.  Essentially, that also means that every `c:when` must have a `c:otherwise` following it inside a `c:choose`, and a `c:choose` *must* surround any `c:when` + `c:otherwise`.  From what I can see, the spec does not refer to nesting `c:choose` elements, so you'd have to try that.

@EJP is right that `c:choose` generally can be translated into a Java `switch`, but there is a difference.  Java switches are *not* required to have mutually exclusive statements inside the conditional, whereas `c:choose` conditionals are.  We know that whatever is inside a `c:when` will be executed if the condition is met, and then no other `c:when` statements appearing below it in that `c:choose` element will be executed.  We cannot necessarily say the same for a Java `switch` statement (though the preferred style is usually mutually exclusive `case` statements).

Let's say that if a person is 13 or 14 years old, we want to send them a birthday card.  If they are 15 or 17, we want to send them a birthday text message.  If they are 16 or 18 (special birthdays), we want to send them both a card and a text.  The code below could accomplish this, and it's a `switch` where more than one of the case statements can be executed if a particular condition is met:

```
switch (age) {

    case 16:                     // falls through (executes case 18)
    case 18: sendBirthdayCard();
             sendBirthdayText();
             break;

    case 13:                     // falls through (executes case 14)
    case 14: sendBirthdayCard();
             break;

    case 15:                     // falls through (executes case 17)
    case 17: sendBirthdayText();
             break;

    default: System.out.println("You are under 13 or over 18 years old.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this construct as though `c:choose` is a Java `switch`; `c:when` is a Java `case`; and `c:otherwise` is a Java `default`.

Comment: This is not completely correct - `c:otherwise` statement is not required. The aforementioned spec says that the `c:choose` statement can contain: `0 or 1 <c:otherwise> action` and it `Must be the last action nested within <c:choose>`